# Can minikube handle oidc authentication?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, openid-connect

I have installed K8S using minikube on ubuntu 16.04 machine with VirtualBox driver.

---

I am confused with various documents that are related to this topic. Some say it is not possible with minikube, but minikube documents that it suitable for test purpose. So i believe that maybe there is a way to achieve oidc authentication with minikube. Is there any link for this which i can follow?

I want to enable oidc in my production environment. But as i am not familiar with K8S, i thought minikube would be ideal to test the feature first. That is the reason i want to know if minikube will support OIDC. If yes, i can make changes here and then replicate the same in my production environment.

I have referred the official documentation, but it does not give detailed explanation on how to obtain the oidc parameters and which files are to be modified.

Comment: Why do you want to use OIDC based auth on minikube, it is intended to be a local setup. You don't share it with other people and minikube automatically configures certs for proper auth.

Comment: I want to see if i can login with my gmail account. I want to enable OIDC based authentication for the production level K8S setup. But i am not familiar with it. So i thought minikube(test environment) would be better to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I have spent time on this, I am answering this question so that it can help someone. 
The answer is YES. Minikube provides a k8s setup which supports the OIDC based authentication. I have been able to configure it. So here is some details on how I configured the kube-apiserver parameters.

`minikube start \
      --extra-config=apiserver.Authorization.Mode=RBAC \
      --extra-config=apiserver.Authentication.OIDC.IssuerURL=https://accounts.google.com \
      --extra-config=apiserver.Authentication.OIDC.UsernameClaim=email \
      --extra-config=apiserver.Authentication.OIDC.ClientID="client_id"`

Also use the k8s-oidc-helper tool and get the refresh-token, id_token and other essential parameters. Then append the contents to the ~/.kube/config file, add the path for the api-server certificate and key. The user is now registered and can use Gmail id to login to k8s

Comment: This answer is lacking detail. When I figure out how to do this, I may come back and make it useful.

Comment: Hi, were you able to do it. I'm also trying to do this