# Configure OIDC in already running minikube

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, openid-connect, minikube

I want to secure running on minikube kubernetes cluster.
My current goal is to block access with kubectl even if you have kubeconfig - is this possible?

I'm trying to do it with OIDC: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#openid-connect-tokens

There are options like kOps or starting minikube with extra config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668534/8563982

But it's not for my case unfortunately - I need to configure already running cluster.

So I tried to override kube-apiserver.yaml like here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/11/08/k8s-api-server-oidc#updating-an-existing-cluster-to-enable-oidc

And I see that kube-apiserver is reloading - I can even break it by wrong syntax - but no authentication is required.

Anyone know where I'm making a mistake?

Thank you in advance